# Tortoisesvn Error: Commit failed (details follow): Can't create directory

Tags: tortoisesvn, trac

OS : Windows 7 (x64)

```
System Information

Trac:   0.11b1
Python: 2.5 (r25:51908, Sep 19 2006, 09:52:17) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
setuptools: 0.6c7
SQLite: 3.5.2
pysqlite:   2.4.0
Genshi: 0.4.4
Subversion: 1.4.6 (r28521)
jQuery: 1.2.1
```

I have a commit error such as below message though I've tried "Clean Up" and "Revert" command. Is there any comments for checking ? I don't remember why it doesn't work.

```
Command: Commit  
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: Can't create directory 'C:\Program Files  
Error:  (x86)\EasyTrac\Data\SVN\Squerrel\db\transactions\20-1.txn': Access denied.  
Completed!:
```

Comment: If Tortoise isn't running as an admin user that would explain it - though the Program Files folder is protected by Windows itself in any case as it contains system files. Why do you have that folder as part of your SVN repository?

Comment: Apologies, to add to the above - looks like there might be something missing from your second copy and paste section above, as the closing quote is missing - what's the full path there, and where is your repository hosted?

Comment: Full Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyTrac\Data\SVN\Squerrel\db\transactions ,and repo directory : C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyTrac\Data\SVN\Squerrel

Comment: Ah, my bad sorry - not reading properly. Looking at section 4 of the EasyTrac guide: https://code.google.com/p/easytrac/wiki/EasyTracGuide, if this is your first commit could this be to do with the permissions it mentions at all? Sounds like it's a local commit, if that's the case file permissions seems a likely possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line of the error message should be enough:

> ```
> Error: Can't create directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\
> ```

Well, of course you can not create files in `C:\Program Files`. At least not without removing a lot of security features.

You have to change the repo directory to something else, to a place where you've got write access to.

Comment: thanks. However, commit was done before in this directory. I do not know why it doesn't work now.

Comment: Looking at the EasyTrac guide linked above that's the default directory for the repositories (the path in the error message is split across two lines which caught me out as well) - it's actually inside the program's installation folder, not the Program Files folder itself. It'd be worth checking the permissions for the repo folder though, and in section 4 of the guide it does explain some files need their permissions changing.